# access pandas axes by axis number

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `pd.Panel` `pn` and `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pn = pd.Panel(np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3), list('XYZ'), list('abc'), list('ABC'))

pn.to_frame().rename_axis('item', 1).unstack()
```

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3), list('abc'), list('ABC'))

df
```

[image]

---

I can access the `items` axis of `pn` with `pn.items` and the `columns` axis of `df` with `df.columns`.

***Question***
But how do I get the `items` axis of `pn` with the number `0` and `minor_axis` axis with the number `2`?  With as many methods that accept the parameter `axis=0`, I'm imagining there is a straight forward way to access axes via number.

***What I've done***
Custom function

```
def get_axis(obj, axis=0):
    if isinstance(obj, pd.Panel):
        m = pd.Series(['items', 'major_axis', 'minor_axis'])
    else:
        m = pd.Series(['index', 'columns'])
    return obj.__getattribute__(m.loc[axis])

print(get_axis(pn, 2))
print(get_axis(pn, 1))
print(get_axis(pn, 0))
print(get_axis(df, 1))
print(get_axis(df, 0))
```

---

```
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object')
Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')
Index([u'X', u'Y', u'Z'], dtype='object')
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C'], dtype='object')
Index([u'a', u'b', u'c'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: do you know about `.xs`? such has : `pn.xs('A', axis=1, level=1)`

Comment: @StevenG yes I do.  That returns a cross section of `pn`.  I want the `Index` object that is the 1st axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.axes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Panel.axes.html) to return a list of the index axis labels as well as the column axis labels and then you could access it via slice-notation.

```
pn.axes
#[Index(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='object'),
# Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object'),
# Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')]
```

Then, you could provide the slices to retrieve the objects:

```
pn.axes[0]
#Index(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype='object')

df.axes[0]
#Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```